# Help with Tkinter Alpha

Tags: python, windows, transparency, tkinter, alpha

I have a python program that has no windows frame and doesn't show up in the taskbar because of **self.overrideredirect(1)**. This program has an options menu (a top level widget) that allows for the alpha to be adjusted with **self.attributes("-alpha", 0.85)**. However when I close out of the options menu my program shows up in the task bar. Obviously I don't want it to do this. I tried invoking the **self.overrideredirect(1)** command after the options menu was closed, but to no avail. Does anyone have a solution/ know of a line that will remove my program from the task bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the override redirect flag you need to withdraw and then deiconify the window to give the window manager a chance to make the change. You might try that.

Also, when you say "close out" the option menu top-level, what exactly do you mean? Are you sure destroying this second top-level window?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's being destroyed. I hit the close button on the upper right. I believe this may be a glitch in Tkinter. However, I found a way around it. Basically I un-invoked the overrideredirect, the re-invoked it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with ease, just copy this code.

```
from Tkinter import *
app = Tk()
root.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.8)
photo = PhotoImage(file="GifImage.gif")
Label(app, image=photo).pack()
app.mainloop()
```