# How to create floating GUI menu list in Python?

Tags: python, drop-down-menu

I am very new to this but I want to create in Python a floating menu list similar to the list that is shown when one right clicks on windows desktop (or generally anywhere). I tried with `tkinter` module but could not figure out how to do this. Can someone please help?

[menu list example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaNKf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think tkinter need to be operated inside its window.

maybe you could coordate place a alpha 0 window,  then bind mouse click event to it.

be sure to put window alpha step to the last, or you wont be able to exam your other modification.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.8)
```

this is from [[Help with Tkinter Alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644113/help-with-tkinter-alpha)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644113/help-with-tkinter-alpha)